# Firefox completelly refuses font load due to EOT

Tags: firefox, webfonts, google-webfonts

I noticed Firefox refuses to load custom fonts on one of my web pages. I'm 90% sure it worked one month ago. Now I use Firefox 43.04 (Windows). The error in the console is:

```
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "PT Serif" style:normal weight:bold stretch:normal src index:0) source: https://localhost:8443/project/fonts/2/pt-serif-v8-latin_latin-ext-700.eot
```

and the html text is rendered with a system font (Times New Roman) instead.

The relevant CSS is:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'PT Serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url('../fonts//pt-serif-v8-latin_latin-ext-700.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('PT Serif Bold'), local('PTSerif-Bold'),
       url('../fonts//pt-serif-v8-latin_latin-ext-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts//pt-serif-v8-latin_latin-ext-700.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts//pt-serif-v8-latin_latin-ext-700.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
}
```

If I remove both lines with *eot*, then it works correctly (web font is used).

The question is, why does it reject the entire font family when the problem is just with one format?
I need *eot* for IE (strange, [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff) claims IE supports WOFF since v9, but it does not seem to work with my IE11).

I downloaded the font files thru https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS line (the one with "Safari, Android, iOS") ends with a comma instead of semicolon. (blush)

The correct (tested to work) version is:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'PT Serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url('../fonts//pt-serif-v8-latin_latin-ext-700.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('PT Serif Bold'), local('PTSerif-Bold'),
       url('../fonts//pt-serif-v8-latin_latin-ext-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts//pt-serif-v8-latin_latin-ext-700.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts//pt-serif-v8-latin_latin-ext-700.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this cause rejection in Firefox.